# How to randomly position a button in a layout?

Tags: android, random, android-relativelayout, imagebutton, absolute

I was wondering how to randomly position an `ImageButton` anywhere around the screen.

I have tried using a `RelativeLayout` but nothing has worked so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share what you tried? Relative layout only will achieve  this

Comment: Submit your work so that one can look into the issue.

Comment: Note: "In Android Studio" is not the problem because "Android Studio" is the IDE.

Comment: RelativeLayout main = new RelativeLayout(this);
    main.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));



    TextView textV = new TextView(this);
        textV.etGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(121, 140, 0, 0);
    textV.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    text.setText("Result ");

main .addView(text);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `FrameLayout` container and set the child view's position using `setTop()` and `setLeft()` to achieve an offset from the top left corner.  If that doesn't work also try setting the `marginTop` and `marginLeft` on the child view's layout paramters.

Comment: Using a RelativeLayout should work fine, you just need to set the position relative to another view

Comment: FrameLayout is mainly used when we need views one on other.

Comment: @priyanka FrameLayout, by statement of documentation, is normally intended for a single child view, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: If I wanted to use marginTop or marginLeft how would this be randomly positioned? Is it possible tor randomly position this even though it is in the xml?

Comment: yes @DougStevenson, but what I meant is: Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. And what the question says is he wants to display multiple image button at random position which is not a single view. yes it can be achieved by FrameLayout as well. :)

Comment: @ZainMerchant, you can't put random numbers into XML.  You will have to do it in code.

Comment: @ZainMerchant Please clear what random means here. You have to mention in xml the position. And in Relative layout position can be anywhere in the screen with help of margins+alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative layout as parent with width and height as match parent. Use a image button with width and height as wrap content or any other fixed value.

Then you can drag the button in preview screen to set it anywhere. Also

```
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

use a combination or one of the above properties in xml to get what you want.